# Divide complex numbers - conditions

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

I have a question. I wrote the operator in C++, which divides complex numbers.

```
    friend const Comp operator/(const Comp& x, const Comp& y)
    {
        Comp temp;
        temp.real = ((x.real * y.real) + (x.imag * y.imag))/(y.real*y.real + y.imag*y.imag);
        temp.imag = ((x.imag * y.real) - (x.real * y.imag))/(y.real*y.real + y.imag*y.imag);
        return temp;
    }
```

And I think about one thing. Is there any situation that we can't divide complex numbers? If yes, I will probably use std:cerr, because in normal division divider must be != 0, so here this part must be != 0 (y.real*y.real + y.imag*y.imag)???

Comment: This is a [mathematical question](https://math.stackexchange.com), not a programming one. Rules are the same: you can't divide only by zero.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDivision.html

Comment: The standard library has a [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) class. Why don't you use it?

Comment: My teacher told us to create our own class.

So (c2 + d2) must be != 0?

Comment: _I will probably use std:cerr_ you might consider throwing an exception here

Comment: BTW, don't calculate `y.real * y.real + y.imag * y.imag` twice. Precompute it into a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any situation that we can't divide complex numbers?

*If* you go for creating your own class for dealing with complex numbers instead of using [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) , try to make it behave like a user would expect. That is:

- `n/d` when `n != 0` and `d == 0` gives `inf, inf` (or possibly `-inf, -inf`).
- `n/d` when both are 0 gives `nan, nan` (or possibly `-nan, -nan`).

---

This is unrelated to the question but nevertheless related to the usability and maintainability of your class:

- The signature:

  ```
  friend const Comp operator/(const Comp& x, const Comp& y)
  ```

  The `Comp` returned by value from this function should not be `const`. Making it `const` will force an expression like:

  ```
  Comp result = complex1 / complex2;
  ```

  to *copy* the result returned by the function. Leave the `const` out and *copy elision* (or NRVO - *Named Return Value Optimization*) is kicking in.
- The implementation:
  You should typically start by implementing the member function

  ```
  Comp& operator/=(const Comp& rhs);
  ```

  that divides `*this` with `rhs` (and returns `*this`). The free `friend` function could then be implemented like this:

  ```
  friend Comp operator/(const Comp& x, const Comp& y) {
      Comp temp(x); // copy construction
      temp /= y;    // operator/=
      return temp;  // NRVO
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking, you can always divide by any complex number other than 0.

However naively implementing the mathematical formula leads to code that will not perform as well as it might.

In your implementation for example the computation of the denominator could overflow to infinity or underflow to 0, even though both the real and imaginary parts of y are non zero and finite.

If your aim is to produce 'production quality' code, you might want to search the web for 'complex division algorithm' or the like, or take a look at the glibc sources.